# Is it possible for an administrator install a program remotely in the background of Windows 7 with the admin share?

Tags: windows-7, remote, administrator

For example, I have Kaspersky.  I can remotely install it and it runs a setup package.  It does this all in the background, first copying its files to that admin share admin$.

Is it possible or is there some tool I can use to do this?  I have a codec I need to install on several users machines.

I am the administrator and have all permissions set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible, and the 'psexec' tool from System Internals can be used to run arbitrary programs remotely in the way you're looking to accomplish. Details on psexec, and a download, can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx); as long as you have admin rights on the remote machine, and can run the codec installer in such a way that it doesn't require user input to complete, it should do what you're looking for.